# Wrapfig not found on full texlive installation

Tags: texlive, wrapfig

Wrapfig doesn't seem to be a part of the full texlive installation any more, is that right, or am I missing something?  EMACS's org-mode export tries to load it and breaks because it isn't found.  I get the same result on two different computers (Arch Linux and Void Linux), with TeX Live 2020 installed manually (not with the OS package manager).

---

I was able to install this, by changing the default repo and typing `tlmgr install wrapfig`.  But how can I make sure everything that belongs to the full installation is installed?  Apparently something went wrong during the original installation.

Comment: What happens if you enter `kpsewhich wrapfig.sty` in the terminal?

Comment: wrapfig is there. What is the exact error message?

Comment: @IanThompson, returns nothing.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, LaTeX error: File `wrapfig.sty' not found.

Comment: OK, try `pdflatex --version`. The first line should show details of the TeX distribution. What do you get?

Comment: @IanThompson, 
texlive 2020

Comment: check in the log-file where article.cls is from and then look if in the same texmf tree there is  wrapfig.sty in tex/latex/wrapfig. If not try to installl it with tlmgr.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thanks.   For some reason it fails to download.

Comment: I suppose there could be something wrong with my local repo, so I'll try to figure out how to use another one ...